# System crashes because of the GPU

Tags: boot, 20.04, freeze, crash

System crashes and I am forced to power off via the power button.

I recently installed **Ubuntu 20.04** about 1 week ago because I wanted to give it a try and forget about Windows a little bit but I am not able to because of these freezes. Also when I shutdown the system it never shutdowns.

Usually this problem is more frequently to happen while I am watching videos but sometimes also while navigating.
I have tried using some tools to fix/repair **/boot**, I also increased the swap size and updated everything but nothing seems to fix it.

I would be very grateful if someone is able to help me figuring out the problem.
Also when I try to shutting down the system it crash too and never shutdowns itself.

### EDITED

PD: I reinstalled Ubuntu 20.04 and still having the same issues. I also tried using only the iGPU instead of the dedicated GPU and the errors gone except for the infinite shutting down.

PC Specs:

- Display 2560x1440 - 144Hz
- NZXT Kraken x62
- Asus Motherboard Sabertooth Z77 (BIOS Version 2104, Up to date)
- 2x8GB RAM
- ASUS HD 7970
- CPU i7-3770K
- Power supply Strike-X 800W (Plus silver)
- (2x) 512GB Samsung SSD 860 EVO (RAID 0, OS Installed here)

RAM INFO

```
Handle 0x005D, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x005B
    Error Information Handle: No Error
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 8192 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: ChannelA-DIMM1
    Bank Locator: BANK 1
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 1867 MT/s
    Manufacturer: 04CD
    Serial Number: 00000000
    Asset Tag: 9876543210
    Part Number: F3-2133C9-8GTX
    Rank: 2
    Configured Memory Speed: 1867 MT/s
```

Last crash log from **`journalctl -b -1 -e`**

```
oct 05 21:46:41 Alex-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1367]: (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   25.18  640 656 752 800  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
oct 05 21:46:41 Alex-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1367]: (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "720x480"x0.0   27.00  720 736 798 858  480 489 495 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
oct 05 21:46:41 Alex-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1367]: (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "720x576"x0.0   27.00  720 732 796 864  576 581 586 625 -hsync -vsync (31.2 kHz e)
oct 05 21:46:41 Alex-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1367]: (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1280x720"x0.0   74.25  1280 1720 1760 1980  720 725 730 750 +hsync +vsync (37.5 kHz e)
oct 05 21:46:41 Alex-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1367]: (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1440x480"x0.0   54.00  1440 1472 1596 1716  480 489 495 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
oct 05 21:46:41 Alex-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1367]: (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1440x576"x0.0   54.00  1440 1464 1592 1728  576 581 586 625 -hsync -vsync (31.2 kHz e)
oct 05 21:46:41 Alex-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1367]: (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  148.50  1920 2008 2052 2200  1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz e)
oct 05 21:46:41 Alex-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1367]: (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  148.50  1920 2448 2492 2640  1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (56.2 kHz e)
oct 05 21:46:41 Alex-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1367]: (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1280x720"x0.0   74.25  1280 1390 1430 1650  720 725 730 750 +hsync +vsync (45.0 kHz e)
oct 05 21:46:41 Alex-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1367]: (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   40.00  800 840 968 1056  600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz e)
oct 05 21:46:41 Alex-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1367]: (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   36.00  800 824 896 1024  600 601 603 625 +hsync +vsync (35.2 kHz e)
oct 05 21:46:41 Alex-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1367]: (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   31.50  640 656 720 840  480 481 484 500 -hsync -vsync (37.5 kHz e)
oct 05 21:46:41 Alex-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1367]: (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   31.50  640 664 704 832  480 489 492 520 -hsync -vsync (37.9 kHz e)
oct 05 21:46:41 Alex-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1367]: (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   30.24  640 704 768 864  480 483 486 525 -hsync -vsync (35.0 kHz e)
oct 05 21:46:41 Alex-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1367]: (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "720x400"x0.0   28.32  720 738 846 900  400 412 414 449 -hsync +vsync (31.5 kHz e)
oct 05 21:46:41 Alex-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1367]: (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  135.00  1280 1296 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (80.0 kHz e)
oct 05 21:46:41 Alex-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1367]: (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   78.75  1024 1040 1136 1312  768 769 772 800 +hsync +vsync (60.0 kHz e)
oct 05 21:46:41 Alex-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1367]: (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   75.00  1024 1048 1184 1328  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (56.5 kHz e)
oct 05 21:46:41 Alex-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1367]: (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   65.00  1024 1048 1184 1344  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (48.4 kHz e)
oct 05 21:46:41 Alex-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1367]: (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   49.50  800 816 896 1056  600 601 604 625 +hsync +vsync (46.9 kHz e)
oct 05 21:46:41 Alex-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1367]: (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   50.00  800 856 976 1040  600 637 643 666 +hsync +vsync (48.1 kHz e)
oct 05 21:46:41 Alex-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1367]: (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1152x864"x0.0  108.00  1152 1216 1344 1600  864 865 868 900 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz e)
oct 05 21:46:41 Alex-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1367]: (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1280x960"x0.0  108.00  1280 1376 1488 1800  960 961 964 1000 +hsync +vsync (60.0 kHz e)
oct 05 21:46:41 Alex-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1367]: (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  108.00  1280 1328 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (64.0 kHz e)
oct 05 21:46:41 Alex-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1367]: (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1440x900"x0.0  106.50  1440 1520 1672 1904  900 903 909 934 -hsync +vsync (55.9 kHz e)
oct 05 21:46:41 Alex-PC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1367]: (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1680x1050"x0.0  146.25  1680 1784 1960 2240  1050 1053 1059 1089 -hsync +vsync (65.3 kHz e)
oct 05 21:46:41 Alex-PC systemd[1336]: gnome-launched-gnome-display-panel.desktop-11575.scope: Succeeded.
oct 05 21:50:03 Alex-PC systemd-resolved[981]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
oct 05 21:55:03 Alex-PC systemd-resolved[981]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
oct 05 22:00:03 Alex-PC systemd-resolved[981]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
oct 05 22:00:25 Alex-PC gnome-shell[1715]: Window manager warning: Invalid WM_TRANSIENT_FOR window 0x1c00005 specified for 0x1c02067.
oct 05 22:04:02 Alex-PC gnome-shell[1715]: Window manager warning: Invalid WM_TRANSIENT_FOR window 0x1c00005 specified for 0x1c022fb.
oct 05 22:05:03 Alex-PC systemd-resolved[981]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
oct 05 22:05:18 Alex-PC gnome-shell[1715]: Window manager warning: Invalid WM_TRANSIENT_FOR window 0x1c00005 specified for 0x1c02465.
oct 05 22:05:19 Alex-PC gnome-shell[1715]: Window manager warning: Invalid WM_TRANSIENT_FOR window 0x1c00005 specified for 0x1c02543.
oct 05 22:08:00 Alex-PC gnome-shell[1715]: Window manager warning: Invalid WM_TRANSIENT_FOR window 0x1c00005 specified for 0x1c027a9.
oct 05 22:09:01 Alex-PC CRON[12125]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
oct 05 22:09:01 Alex-PC CRON[12126]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; fi)
oct 05 22:09:01 Alex-PC CRON[12125]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
oct 05 22:09:37 Alex-PC systemd[1]: Starting Clean php session files...
oct 05 22:09:38 Alex-PC systemd[1]: phpsessionclean.service: Succeeded.
oct 05 22:09:38 Alex-PC systemd[1]: Finished Clean php session files.
oct 05 22:10:03 Alex-PC systemd-resolved[981]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
oct 05 22:13:01 Alex-PC gnome-shell[1715]: Window manager warning: Invalid WM_TRANSIENT_FOR window 0x1c00005 specified for 0x1c029db.
oct 05 22:13:03 Alex-PC gnome-shell[1715]: Window manager warning: Invalid WM_TRANSIENT_FOR window 0x1c00005 specified for 0x1c02ac5.
```

**SHUTDOWN FREEZE**:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fk8sf.jpg

Comment: Is there a .crash file in /var/crash, with a created-time corresponding to the freeze? How long do you wait for the freeze to resolve itself before holding the power button?

Comment: List your computer make and model, also your specs such as CPU, in your question.  Different hardware will narrow down problem.

Comment: On first crashes I have waited hours but it never recovers. After a while monitor goes black and the devices stop working